# Vectorize nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, vectorization

given 2 list: solved and country. Need to conjugate each element of country at the end of each of  solved ones... and obtain a kinda of matrix `frac`

I need please suggestion on how speed up the 3 level of loop :

```
 for i in range(0,len(solved),lung):
            h = solved[i:i+lung]
            for j in range(len(country)):
                g = [h[k]+country[j] for k in range(len(h))]
                frac.append(g)
```

Comment: Can you provide the dummy input and expected output?

Comment: solved= ['a','aa','ab','fa','sa','ea','wa','ga'] country=['.sa','.ge','.er','.il','.ok','.ka','.ga'] and the final g == ['a.sa','a.ge',....,'aa.sa','aa.ge',...]

Comment: lung represent of length of the chunk

Comment: Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with very easy code as follows:

```
import numpy as np

solved_array = np.array(solved)
country_array = np.array(country)
    
# Reshape the arrays for broadcasting
solved_reshaped = solved_array[:, np.newaxis]
country_reshaped = country_array[np.newaxis, :]
frac = np.char.add(solved_reshaped,country_reshaped).tolist()
```

this code result over 100+ time faster than previous proposed
Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
frac = []    
for solv in solved:
        frac+=[solv+x for x in country]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
frac = [[s + c for s in solved] for c in country]
```

(I don't understand the use of `lung`)

The output is:

```
[['a.sa', 'aa.sa', 'ab.sa', 'fa.sa', 'sa.sa', 'ea.sa', 'wa.sa', 'ga.sa'], ['a.ge', 'aa.ge', 'ab.ge', 'fa.ge', 'sa.ge', 'ea.ge', 'wa.ge', 'ga.ge'], ['a.er', 'aa.er', 'ab.er', 'fa.er', 'sa.er', 'ea.er', 'wa.er', 'ga.er'], ['a.il', 'aa.il', 'ab.il', 'fa.il', 'sa.il', 'ea.il', 'wa.il', 'ga.il'], ['a.ok', 'aa.ok', 'ab.ok', 'fa.ok', 'sa.ok', 'ea.ok', 'wa.ok', 'ga.ok'], ['a.ka', 'aa.ka', 'ab.ka', 'fa.ka', 'sa.ka', 'ea.ka', 'wa.ka', 'ga.ka'], ['a.ga', 'aa.ga', 'ab.ga', 'fa.ga', 'sa.ga', 'ea.ga', 'wa.ga', 'ga.ga']]
```

Let me know if this is what you needed.

Comment: thanks ! yes is very compact code and its works fine , but is equivalent to mine: are practically nested loops. I mean, doesn't burst the speed that much. I was more thinking to a way of vectorization for a kind of instant processing. The example are with short lists, mine real ones are of 50k to 1M items, and our code takes minutes...too much